# Why is netstat deprecated?

Tags: linux, netstat

I've heard many times now that it is, and I'm mostly using `ss` now. But I sometimes get frustrated with differences between the two, and I would love some insight.

Also, I can't be the only one who thinks of Hitler when using `ss`. Not a great name.

Comment: Is there anything more to it than the usual iproute2 fanboyism?

Comment: I agree that `ss` feels a bit clunky compared to `netstat`, but `ip` has always seemed way better than `ifconfig` (just an opinion).

Comment: It may not be strictly SEesque, but thanks @jordanm for answering the question(s), "What? it is? Well what do I use _instead_?  :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found an [article on deprecation from 2011](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/). It seems like the whole `net-tools` package was not maintained for a while and so it was deprecated. In Debian 9 it is not even installed by default. From [the project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/files/?source=navbar) it seems like there were no updates at least since 2011.

But you can easily install `netstat` (and e.g. `ifconfig`) and keep using them. I would probably only use them for listing stuff though.

Installing on Debian 9:

```
apt-get install net-tools
```

PS: For more information you might want to see another Q&A about `ifconfig` deprecation (`ifconfig` is part of the same package): https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig

Answer (score -3):

Why is `netstat` deprecated?  Because it says so in the man page:

> ```
> NOTE
>    This program is obsolete.  Replacement for netstat is ss.   Replacement
>    for  netstat -r is ip route.  Replacement for netstat -i is ip -s link.
>    Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.
> ```

Why did the developers deprecate `netstat`?  I don't know.

It's open source, though.  If you want to revive it, make it more useful and get it "undeprecated," feel free to do so.

Comment: Your answer is 'because it is' or 'I don't know'?

Comment: @onlyanegg, your question is "Why have I been told that it's deprecated?" or "Why did the developers decide to deprecate it?"

Comment: it is 'Why did the developers deprecate it?'

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/77d0c1b2a55c1af31cce4df68da7bf93c8155111/

Comment: This doesn't answer anything. How did this get upvoted?

Comment: What steps should one go through to revive it and get it undeprecated?